# How to pass for loop index inside ActionListener's actionPerformed [Java]

Tags: java, loops, variables, action

I was wondering if there is a way to assign click event using a loop.
Quick example of what I looking for:
Where each button will do actions inside `myMethod(int)`.

So `button[2]` should do `myMethod(2)` and so on.

```
// imports...    
public class MyClass {

        private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10];

        public MyClass() {
            // constructor

            for ( int i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; i++ ) {
             this.buttons[i].addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {                  
                        MyClass.this.myMethod(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public void myMethod( int id ) {
            // perform actions
            //...
        }



    }
```

The code above throws error that the variable must be final or effecively final. I know why, but how can I do similiar thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create temporary final variable and assign `i` value to it. Now you can use the final variable to pass it to `myMethod`, like below:

```
// imports...    
public class MyClass {

    private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10];

    public MyClass() {
        // constructor

        for (int i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; i++) {
            final int myFinalIndex = i;
            this.buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    MyClass.this.myMethod(myFinalIndex);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void myMethod(int id) {
        // perform actions
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! :))